# Is interceptor really disabled by default?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, jboss-weld, weld

I ran into this confusion today. [Quote from Weld's documentation (right under Section 9.3)](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/2.1.0.Final/en-US/html/interceptors.html),

> By default, all interceptors are disabled. We need to enable our
>   interceptor. We can do it using beans.xml descriptor of a bean
>   archive. However, this activation only applies to the beans in that
>   archive.

However, in the project that I am currently working on, I have an interceptor for profiling a method. My `META-INF/beans.xml` is basically empty:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                           http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

Yet I still get expected logs from that profiling interceptor. So, as the title goes, is interceptor really disabled by default?

BTW, I use `weld-se` for CDI functionality in the project, since CDI is the only thing I need for the project from the Java EE stack.

### update

After messing around interceptors today, I find that if the old `@Interceptors` is used to indicate the interception implementation class, you don't need to specify anything in the `beans.xml`. However, if you use interceptor binding, i.e., use the `@Interceptor` annotation to indicate an interceptor class, you must enable interception by adding the interceptor class to the `beans.xml`. According to my experience, this is still true for CDI 1.1, as indicated by the version in the `beans.xml` above. BTW, I use `org.jboss.weld.se:weld-se:2.0.4.Final` for CDI implementation in this case, which I believe implements CDI 1.1.

Comment: If you could please link to the documentation.  Is it possible that you found a Weld 1.0 or 1.1 doc, but are using Weld 2.0?

Comment: @JohnAment: Good point. I didn't notice which version of Weld my original quote belongs to. In any case, I updated the quote from weld 2.1.0.Final documentation, along with its link.

Comment: Ok, then yes.  I see now.  Yes, when you use `@Interceptors` the interceptors are on by default, since you've created a tight coupling between the intercepted object and the interceptor, it will end up enabling it.  However, as noted in the docs `@Interceptors` is provided by the Interceptor spec, not the EJB or CDI specs, as a result only the rules of the Interceptor spec are expected to be applied (you may find others are as well, but it's not portable).

Comment: @JBT As per CDI 1.0 implemented by Weld 1.x for JEE6 specs. I confirm your finding. beans.xml does need to have an Interceptors tag with the interceptor class name as the value if @Interceptors(InterceptorClass.class) is used. In case you prefer the annotation approach (@MyLoggingInterceptor for example), then declaring the com.myorg.LoggingIntercepttingClass in beans.xml is a must.

Comment: Annotating the interceptor with  `@Priority` will enable it, without the inclusion of beans.xml. e.g. `@Priority(Interceptor.Priority.APPLICATION)`

Answer (score 9):

To confirm JBT findings in his EDIT. As per CDI specifications 1.0 of JSR-299 implemented by Weld 1.0 for JEE6 specs. Please reference [this pointer](http://www.cdi-spec.org/faq/), which I quote:

> By default, a bean archive has no enabled interceptors bound via interceptor bindings. An interceptor must be explicitly enabled by listing the fully qualified class name in a child `<class>` element of `<interceptors>`. **as in Approach 2 below**

Follows an example:

### First mandatory step is the interceptor binding:

```
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
public @interface Loggable {
}
```

### Second mandatory step is the Intercepting Class:

```
@Interceptor
@Loggable
public class LoggingInterceptor {

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object logMethodEntry(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("In LoggingInterceptor..................... before method call");
        Object returnMe = ctx.proceed();
        System.out.println("In LoggingInterceptor..................... after method call");
        return returnMe;
    }
}
```

### Third step can be achieved using either one of the following approaches

#### Approach 1, an empty beans.xml will do the job

```
@Stateless
@Interceptors(LoggingInterceptor.class)     //class interception
public class Displayer implements DisplayerLocal {

    @Override
    //@Interceptors(LoggingInterceptor.class)  //method interception
    public void displayHi() {
        System.out.println(".....Hi there............");
    }
}
```

#### Approach 2, needs the beans.xml as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
    <interceptors>
        <class>com.companyname.LoggingInterceptor</class>
    </interceptors>
</beans>
```

Then the intercepted class:

```
@Stateless
@Loggable       //class interception
public class Displayer implements DisplayerLocal {

    @Override
    //@Loggable      //method interception
    public void displayHi() {
        System.out.println(".....Hi there............");
    }
}
```

Comment: We migrated an application to Java 11 and "Approach 1 -  empty beans.xml" does not work anymore (on TomEE & Wildfly). We switched to Approach 2 that works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Interceptors and decorators are enabled from `1.1` version by default. See the [highlights](http://cdi-spec.org/) of the new CDI spec.

Comment: I have to say that I disagree with your answer. Please see my update for why.